# Dirac spinor parity

Tags: dirac-equation, spinors, parity

I'm not sure I understand the effect of a parity transform on a Dirac spinor $\left(
\begin{array}{c}
\psi_R\\
\psi_L\\
\end{array}
\right)$. I've been given the definitions $P\psi=\gamma_0\psi$, which would mean swapping $\psi_L$ and $\psi_R$. I've also been told that $P\bar{\psi}=\bar{\psi}\gamma_0$. Based on the definition $\bar{\psi}=\psi^{\dagger}\gamma_0$, then 
$$P\bar{\psi}=\psi^{\dagger}\gamma_0^2 = \psi^{\dagger} = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
\psi_R^* && \psi_L^*\\
\end{array}
\right)$$
But then the parity transform wouldn't have had any effect on $\bar{\psi}$, which doesn't seem right, so where did my reasoning go wrong?

I've looked at these two questions:

- [Dirac spinor and Weyl spinor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/95457/)
- [Parity transformations and massless Dirac spinors](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/255438/)

But I don't really understand the notation, or whether it addresses my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does $\bar \psi$ look like in the first place? Well, it is $\psi^\dagger \gamma^0 = (\psi_L^*\ \psi_R^*)$ according to your choice of $\psi$. It makes sense that parity swaps these slots.

$$ (\psi_L^*\ \psi_R^*) \stackrel{P}\to (\psi_R^*\ \psi_L^*)$$